# What impact do broken families and little church attendance have on black youth's odds of success?

Tags: religion, education, inequality, income

Dinesh D'Souza theorizes in his book, *The End of Racism*, that black culture is preventing blacks from succeeding in America. The institutional racism from the past is gone, and in general blacks only face what he terms, [rational discrimination](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NvFG6jH_ocY#t=7m24s)<sup>[Video removed]</sup>.

Rational discrimination is what makes perfectly logical cab drivers less likely to pick up young black males or makes people decide to choose to walk on [one side](https://robcartwrightphotoblog.files.wordpress.com/2013/08/street-photography-finsbury-park-st-thomass-road-n4-north-london-black-suit-briefcase-hat-beard-umbrella-man-portraiture-rob-cartwright.jpg) of the street [or another](https://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2013/05/12/article-2323255-19BBB3FC000005DC-641_634x681.jpg) depending upon who is walking towards them.

D'Souza argues that the disparate impact on blacks [educational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racial_wage_gap_in_the_United_States#Educational_disparities) and [income](https://www.census.gov/hhes/www/income/data/historical/people/2013/p54.xls)<sup>[Broken link]</sup> are largely a product of black culture's lack of focus on family, church, and small business instead of discrimination.

**Are there any studies that backup D'Souza's claim?** (I.e. What is the impact on educational scores/attainment level and income of black children who come from broken families versus those that are intact. As well as families that attend church regularly and those that do not)

Comment: I'm not totally clear what you're asking. Are you asking, in general, how much racial inequality can be explained by African-Americans themselves rather than present racism, or are you asking for specific comparisons, and if so, what are they?

Comment: @Avi, for example in [this answer](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/21922/does-getting-married-prevent-violence-against-women-and-children/21957#21957), the BJS discovered that unmarried women with children and a live-in boyfriends had a 10x greater risk of domestic violence than women with children married to the child's father. I was wondering if an statistic show that black children from unbroken families perform better educationally/economically than black children from broken families. (Same thing with church attendance). If their are figures that have measured ...

Comment: how much discrimination has an impact on education/income of black children that would be good as well (I don't have high hopes that those figures exist)

Comment: The question isn't especially falsifiable, as broken families and low church attendance would impact any other segment of the population. The problem being that correlation does not equal causation; and any large ethnic cohort has a wealth of information that can correlate any which way you want them to. Observational studies are highly susceptible to _post hoc ergo propter hoc_ and thus should be excluded from any viable answer.

Comment: @LateralFractal, I suggest you petition all the universities to close their soft science programs, sociology, psychology, etc. You can use regression analysis to hold other variables constant to determine if a particular variable has an impact on the outcome of a group. Scientists do this all the time when random controlled studies are impractical/impossible.

Comment: This like asking for data to back up something Rush Limbaugh or Bill Maher says. There's often a thread of truth hidden in a whole pile of political posturing and punditry. Seems way out of scope for a Q/A format.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that D'Souza has said things like this: http://talkingpointsmemo.com/livewire/dinesh-dsouza-african-americans He's really in the business of pushing buttons, more than careful, thoughtful analysis.

Comment: @DA., well he is right. They are better off.

Comment: @user1873 it's not an issue of right or wrong. It's just an absurd thing to say and is done merely for showmanship.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to answer a slightly different question: "For those three aspects of life (family, church, small business) are there studies that do show that blacks value those more or less than other races?"

I wasn't able to find any studies that on appreciation of small business success for African Americans. They do [own less](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/titles/content/9780262514941_sch_0001.pdf) small businesses.

**Lack of focus on family**
I'm not sure how to measure exactly that so I'll just cite statistics that can be seen as proxies.

Finding a suitable spouse is hard. Finding a spouse where there is about a 33% chance of him being incarnated or higher poverty rates certainly doesn't make it easier - as seen in "Understanding Young Women's Marriage Decisions: The Role of Labor and Marriage Market Conditions" (Francine D. Blau, Lawrence M. Kahn, and Jane Waldfogel).
But if those two are controlled for there are [virtually no](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2780733?uid=3737864&uid=382794691&uid=2&uid=3&uid=60&sid=21104539052031) [discrepancies](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/353890?uid=3737864&uid=382794691&uid=2&uid=3&uid=60&sid=21104539416911) in marriage rates between whites and blacks.

What about divorce rates? Blacks divorce [consistently (page 26f)](http://www.cdc.gov/nchs/data/series/sr_23/sr23_022.pdf) (e.g. for all unemployment and age of marriage levels) more often.

A further measure is percentage of out-of-wedlock births. About [two-thirds](http://www.census.gov/prod/2013pubs/acs-21.pdf) of African American children are born out of wedlock (the study does not attempt to control those figures with income levels. It does find that income correlates well (0.6) with out-of-wedlock births).
This is further exacerbated by the [fact](http://www.theatlantic.com/sexes/archive/2013/06/understanding-out-of-wedlock-births-in-black-america/277084/) that black married woman get less children than black white woman. From the pictures I'm eyeballing a difference of 20%. That would mean the the two-thirds would need to be reduced by a fifth (so 0.53).

That does not mean an absent father figure nor lack of male role models (see "The Black Extended Family" (E.g. the US census 2003 showed that black kids are three times more likely than whites to live with their grandparents) and "Joyce Ladner, Tomorrow's Tomorrow: The Black Woman 2") or even that values historically seen to be taught by the father can not be taught by [mothers](http://www.nytimes.com/1995/05/11/us/women-are-becoming-equal-providers.html).

**Lack of focus on church attendance**
A [Gallup poll](http://www.gallup.com/poll/141044/americans-church-attendance-inches-2010.aspx) from 2010 showed Hispanic black attendance on 52%, non-Hispanic black attendance on 55%.
That puts them on par with the stereotypical religious segments (People from the south, Republicans, conservatives, People older than 65) who range from 51 to 55%.
AFAIK there are not studies on how much income affects church attendance for blacks. For non-Hispanic whites there is a direct [positive](http://nationalmarriageproject.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/No-Money-No-Honey-Wilcox-FINAL.pdf) correlation between education (which has an correlation and plausible causation to income) and church attendance.

Comment: I tried my best to leave my liberal bias out of this answer but only very few studies account for the higher poverty rate amongst blacks at all. And that poverty rate obviously exacerbates all other aspects, just as those exacerbate the likelihood of poverty. Then the incarnation rate is mostly caused by stricter sentencing for non-violent drug offenses which still are a institutional racism. Institutional in this context not meaning "written in law" but inherent in the current judicial and police system.

Comment: For your last section, **completely false** isn't the right conclusion. You need studies that hold other variables constant. What you are really looking for is blacks who attend church verses **blacks that do not attend church**. You shouldn't be comparing them versus other races and saying, well their average is the same as the average of other races. The whole point is to see if church attendance has an impact. (I.e. Maybe Hispanics/whites/Asians that attend church do better than Hispanics/whites/Asians that do not attend church.

Comment: Your second point doesn't have any data. It just states that out of wedlock births and broken families are a bigger problem in black culture (we already know that). What I want to know is what effect that has on the income/educational level of their children. "Finding a spouse where there is about a 33% chance of him being incarnated or higher poverty rates certainly doesn't make it easier," isn't that rather racist to say that black women can only marry black men? Also, no one is putting a gun to black women's heads and saying they must have children even if they cannot find a man to marry.

Comment: Until someone finds other studies I'll note that the church attendance statistic also is only a proxy. I'm not saying that they can't - but they don't: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1741-3729.2008.00491.x/pdf (I guess because of http://blog.okcupid.com/index.php/race-attraction-2009-2014/) I'm not sure if you want me to claim that growing up in a divorced household is worse for African American kids compared to (NH?) whites or whether it would suffice to point out that often having both parents around is beneficial

Comment: It would be important to note **how much better** it is to have both parents around. If it has a large impact (5x - 10x the RR), that might explain why blacks are at the bottom of the education/income scale, since 72% of children are born out of wedlock.

Comment: @user1873 80% of children in Sweden are born out of wedlock. Pulling out individual stats like this is interesting, but ultimately just leads to punditry ala Dinesh D'Souza's playbook. It's good for selling books and getting booked on cable news, but not great, in and of itself, for true analysis of complex socio-economic problems.

Comment: Also, you *can't* come to meaningful conclusions by pulling these stats out and ignoring the other variables. You are asking for a direct correlation between 'success' and 'going to church' but there won't be a *direct* connection.

Comment: @DA. It is good to know that **race** is a meaningless stat when comparing income inequality, education, etc. I guess it is time we stopped listening to all the Al Sharptons et. al. who say that discrimination is keeping black people down since we cannot come to any meaningful conclusions.

Comment: @user1873 it's meaningless *in and of itself*. You're simply doing what Dinesh does...taking two stats and claiming there's a direct correlation to further your viewpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose a lot depends upon how one defines institutional racism. Anecdotally speaking, I've lived in places in the U.S. where there was a very clear racial divide. There was, what one might term, localized institutional racism against African Americans. I saw it in businesses, and even in the office where I worked. Gone are the days of George Wallace openly declaring a divide of segregation or the murderer of Medgar Evers walking free for 30 years. It is likely much smaller than in years past, but I don't believe it's gone.

On the notion of church attendance being analogous to cultural success for a racial group in America, I think the data says otherwise. Most studies show church attendance by race is highest among African Americans in the U.S.